# Can't deserialize XML to object

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm having problems deserializing an XML response that I receive from a web service. The response looks like this:

```
<CreateSubscribersResultCollection xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CreatedSubscriberIds xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:long>206464306</a:long>
        <a:long>306664316</a:long>
    </CreatedSubscriberIds>
    <FailedCreatedSubscribers xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
</CreateSubscribersResultCollection>
```

The code I use to deserialize the XML looks like this:

```
internal T GetQueuedResults<T>(string url)
{
    WebRequest request = GetRequestObject(url, "GET");
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var response = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(responseStream);

        return response;
    }
}
```

When I deserialize (passing the type `CreateSubscribersResultCollection`) I get **no errors** at all, instead the `CreatedSubscriberIds` has the length of `0`. I am pretty sure that the error lies in how I've designed the `CreateSubscribersResultCollection` class, but I can't figure out what the error might be. The class looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CreateSubscribersResultCollection : RequestBase
{
    [XmlArray("CreatedSubscriberIds")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(long))]
    public List<long> CreatedSubscriberIds { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FailedCreatedSubscribers")]
    public string FailedCreatedSubscribers { get; set; }
}
```

When I instantiate the class and serialize it, for debugging purposes, I get these results:

```
<CreateSubscribersResultCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CreatedSubscriberIds>
        <long>206464306</long>
        <long>306664316</long>
    </CreatedSubscriberIds>
    <FailedCreatedSubscribers />
</CreateSubscribersResultCollection>
```

I hope there's someone out there who knows what I'm doing wrong. I have been banging my head against this for too long now and Google has been no help to me.

Comment: You need to specify namespace. Try to add namespace
 in XmlArrayItem XmlElement attributes.

Comment: Have you tried to mark your properties with the DataMember attribute?

Comment: @EmmieGabrielleLewis Lewis, yes i have, to no avail.

Comment: @Reniuz, i know how to add the namespace. but i cant get the desired results (looking like the response xml).

Comment: @sundown looks like you didn't know. eyossis wrote what i told and that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the namespace like that:

```
    [DataContract]
public class CreateSubscribersResultCollection : RequestBase
{
    [XmlArray("CreatedSubscriberIds")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(long), Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
    public List<long> CreatedSubscriberIds { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FailedCreatedSubscribers")]
    public string FailedCreatedSubscribers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `GetResponseStream()` has a data in it. To test try saving this into a file instead of doing network connection. Save it to data file and deserialize. If it is being serialized, that is most of the battle. Deserializing shouldn't be problem if it was serialized properly.

Comment: the responsestream has data. i am also not the one who has serialised the data in the first place, i get the xml from a webservice.

Comment: You need all the classes that was used to serialize the data. You need the actual classes and everything. When there is deserialization and there is a problem, it usually says recursion exception or no data. Make sure the class contracts are similar to how the data was serialized in the first place. The class used in serialization should be 100% similar to the class during deserialization. Also include [DataMember] in the properties and values.